flutter RadialGradient background to scaffold
I am trying to achieve RadialGradient which looks like waves as shown in below image.

But all I could achieve is

My code
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
 const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   body: Center(
    child: Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: RadialGradient(
          colors: [
            Color(0xfffabe76),
            Colors.white,
          ],
          center: Alignment.centerRight,
          radius: 0.8,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
   );
 }
 }

Help me achieve this.

Try to change the radius from "0.8" to "1.0" and use opacity with your color something like this: "Color(0xfffabe76)
.withOpacity(0.6)" and if you need to make more changes then just play with the radius and opacity.
